# iPhone play sound on splash screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I just want to play a little ding on when the splash screen loads.  I'm guesing that goes in the RootViewControler.m under viewDidLoad.  As for playing the audio file I'm googled and found a lot of things I haven't been able to make work.

What type of audio file should it be?  wav mp3 etc. or does it matter.

I'm not sure what ofType@"caf" is, but here is what I have found, when I try it I get AVAudioplayer undeclared (which I'm thinking is a total newb error but don't know):

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                               pathForResource:@"click"
                                               ofType:@"caf"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
    [click play];
    [click release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Thank you for any help,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :
**pathForResource:ofType:**

Returns the full pathname for the resource identified by the specified name and file extension.

```
  - (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension
```

The program looks for a file called click.caf in your main bundle. The warning about AVPlayer being undeclared means that you have to add the AVFoundationFramework to your project and import the proper `.h` - file with `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you haven't added the AVFoundation framework. Once you add the AVFoundation.framework, you'll need to `#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>` and hopefully it will work.